# How to fastest way to retrieve data from mysql to asp.net?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net

Im getting very slow loading in my page retrieving data from mysql

````
                string cda = "Select * from citymaster where country_code='" + ddl1.SelectedValue + "'";
                MySqlDataAdapter ad = new MySqlDataAdapter(cda, connection);
                DataTable dtb = new DataTable();
                ad.Fill(dtb);

                ddl_city.DataSource = dtb;
                ddl_city.DataTextField = "city_name";
                ddl_city.DataValueField = "city_name";
                ddl_city.DataBind();
                ddl_city.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select City", "0"));
       ```
````

Comment: First suggestion would be in `Select` use only needed columns. Second one will be to check for index present on table.

Comment: Third one will be to read about **Sql Injection**

Comment: Use dapper if you really want speed